# How to test a Symfony BinaryFileResponse with php-unit

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I have written an action which create a temporary file and returned it with a `BinaryFileResponse` and delete it after. 
Something like this :

```
    $response = new BinaryFileResponse($this->getFile($filename) );
    $response->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', $this->getFileMimeType($filename));

    return $response;
```

Where `$filename` refers to a temporary file.

It's working great, my file is sent and deleted after. But I cannot test it.

Here the summary of my test :

```
public function testIndex()
{
   $client = static::createClient();

   $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/post');
   $response =  $this->client->getResponse();

   if($response instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse )
   {
        $fullpath = '/some/path/filename';
        $this->assertFileEquals($fullpath, $response->getFile()->getPathname());
   }
}
```

But during the time of the test the file has already been deleted...

```
jerome@api $ phpunit -c .
PHPUnit 5.7.27 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

F

Time: 3.08 seconds, Memory: 30.25MB

There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\CoreBundle\Controller\ExperienceControllerTest::testAPICall 
Failed asserting that file "/Users/jerome/Developpement/api/app/../var/cache/experience_file_15b5ae9bc7f668" exists.
```

I have found bug request on the symfony [github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/16293) but no solution yet. 
Any idea of how I can achieve this ?

My ideas so far :

1 Remove `deleteFileAfterSend`depending on the environment, but I found this solution quit ugly.
2 Stop using `WebTestCase` and start using cURL but I don't want to lose code coverage and it seems to be a lot of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution, I just send the file without using `BinaryFileResponse`.

```
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type'     => 'image/png',
    'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="image.png"');

return new Response(file_get_contents('myFile.png'), 200, $headers);
```

To delete the file after sending, just save the result of `file_get_contents` in a variable and delete the file, then send the response.

For testing, it's really easy :

```
    $fileContent = file_get_contents($filepath);
    $this->assertEquals($response->getContent(),$fileContent,"File content doesn't match requirement");
```

Answer (score 0):

Symfony's test client stores the output of the controller action internally. You can use that for the test.

```php
$fileName = '/some/path/filename';
$fileContent = file_get_Contents($fileName);

$client = static::createClient();
$client->request('GET', '/post');

$this->assertSame($fileContent, $client->getInternalResponse()->getContent());
```